# How to hide border of cells in wpf toolkit datagrid?

Tags: c#-3.0, wpftoolkit

I want to hide the borders of cells in wpf toolkit datagrid (like ShowGridLine property of WPF grid).

How can I achive this behaviour?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It can be achieved by setting GridLinesVisibility="None"